# Service Fabric - Node in Error state

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've spun up a Service Fabric cluster in Azure and suddenly my node is in error state - Unfortunate but this can happen.

[image: Service Fabric Cluster in Azure Portal]

When I check Service Fabric Explorer I can see that the node is in error state but the error doesn't really give me any hints since I really didn't do anything.

[image]

I haven't found a way to fix it and worst-case scenario was to restart the node but I was unable to find this capability.

Did anybody have this issue before or can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Service Fabric Explorer, there is a Nodes view below the clusters. You can select the node and choose details to see more information about the node. You may be able to see something that indicates what is wrong. There are also 5 actions that can be taken on the node Activate, Deactivate (pause), Deactivate (Restart), Deactivate (remove data) and remove node state.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just found out the other day and it's working again.